# How can I close BufferedReader in the while loop

Tags: java, bufferedreader

When I was trying to close the BufferedReader in the while loop, it will throws an `IOException: Stream closed` when the loop execute the second time.

My code is like:

```
import java.io.*;

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int option = 0;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        while (option != -1) {
            try {
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                try {
                    option = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    option = -1;    
                }

                br.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println(e);
                System.exit(-4);
            }

            System.out.println(option);
        }
    }
}
```

What should I do to close BufferedReader? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I close BufferedReader in the while loop

You *are* closing it in the `while` loop, and that's the *problem.*

Open it *before* the loop, and don't close it at all, as it's wrapped around `System.in`, which can't be reopened.

Comment: Did you mean I do not need to close the BufferedReader if I open it before the loop?

Comment: No, I mean you shouldn't close it because it's wrapped around `System.in`. Oh wait, that's what I actually said.

Answer (score -1):

You can do a couple of things

```
    try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           try {
                option = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                option = -1;    
            }

            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            br.close();
            System.exit(-4);
        }
 }
```

If you're using a recent enough version

```
    try {
           br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
           try {
                option = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                option = -1;    
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e);
            System.exit(-4);
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
```

If an exception is incurred, the code will progress immediately to the catch statement, and then the finally statement if it exists.

Also, the whole point of exception handling is to take care of a exception that might happen. You normally wouldn't want to exit a system in an exception--since the code will terminate if you didn't handle the exception anyways.

Comment: The presence of a `while` loop in the title, the question, and the code contradicts any possible suggestion that he wants to exit the JVM or even terminate the loop on a `NumberFormatException`.